# Heap Memory Allocation in ARM64 Assembly without the C Standard Library

Tags: linux, assembly, arm, arm64, armv8

I'm trying to find a way to do heap memory allocation in armv8-a assembly, and after looking through syscall tables and trying to look at the Linux Programmer's Manual I can't find any way to allocate and de-allocate memory at runtime without using malloc and free from the c standard library.

I've looked at `brk()` but that doesn't appear to have any way to de-allocate memory.

Comment: brk and sbrk are indeed the building blocks. You can shrink by setting a smaller value. Here is a good primer on how this is used to build malloc. https://azeria-labs.com/heap-exploitation-part-1-understanding-the-glibc-heap-implementation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is preferred to `sbrk/brk` for most purposes in modern programs.  Use `munmap` to free.

By the way, `brk` can deallocate memory; simply pass an address lower than the current break point.  But this does limit you to freeing in a last-in-first-out fashion.